# After converting repository from hg to git, how to migrate additional changesets?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

After using [fast-export](https://github.com/frej/fast-export) to migrate a mercurial repository to git, I've found that open named branches that weren't merged to default weren't converted. Now I want to import the outstanding changesets on these branches to the new git repos.

I've tried various approaches including hg-git and hg export, but the problem with these approaches is that the changesets or diffs I want to migrate have different changeset ids, and the processes error out since the history cannot be found.

I'm considering writing a script to automate exporting the changesets from Mercurial, locate the corresponding parent changeset in the new git repo, import to the git stage, and commit, but I'm wondering if a tool for something like this - importing diffs without matching history - already exists. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, what the import needed was more complex than any conversion tool could support. I wrote a C# script that would export patches from the Mercurial repository, modify them as needed to match the new Git repo layout, then generate a series of git commands which, when run, would import the patches and make commits on the branch to import. This has worked well over a number of branches we've needed to import.

[The LinqPad script can be found here](http://share.linqpad.net/6bjv7k.linq) and a [Gist can be found here](https://gist.github.com/codekaizen/811d8265a750edc14f29fd7d2c612269).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert hg to git by these steps:

1. In TortoiseHg -> global setting -> Extensions Tab -> select hggit
2. Create an initial git repo:

`mkdir git
 cd git
 git init
 cd ..`

3. Clone a hg repo and push it to git

`hg clone <URL for hg repo>
 hg bookmarks hg
 hg push ../git`

4. In git repo, find the changeset for hg

`cd ..
 cd git
 git checkout hg
 git log`

Then you will find the log histories.

**update**

If you still want to use faste-export to migrate. You can try below steps:

Inspired by [migrate from mercurial to git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git), we can also create a changeset mapping file by `hg log | grep changeset: | sort | uniq | sed 's/changeset: *//' > ../changeset`.

When migrate hg to git just try `/path/for/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/for/hg-repo -A /path/for/changeset` instead (beacause windows OS seems has trouble to usehg-fast-export.sh, so sorry for that I can’t try it before update the answer).

Comment: Thanks Marina - I did try this approach, the problem is that the log histories do not match up anymore since they have different changeset hashes. This means I cannot pull any changesets from the converted hg repo into the current git repo, since the changeset range I want to import has a different history.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I eventually had to write a script to handle the history and path differences between the original HG repository and the already converted Git repo.